# Follow a growing JSON file while removing one attribute

Tags: json, bash, cron, filtering

I want to follow a JSON logfile `log.json` and remove one attribute. I want to forward the file, without this attribute, to a log server. I can remove the attribute every 10s but I need to remember the position somehow to get only the lines which were added.

```
tail -f file.json | jq 'del(.timestamp)' >> filtered_file.json
```

Now I want to be able to resume such a process. Is there any simple way how I can get the json entries which were added since last time I checked?

I want to tell rsyslog to forward the `filtered_file.json` - however this only makes sense if this is constantly growing. I can run the filtering with cron every 60s or so.

Comment: we could automatically send the output of the tail command(keeoing it running in the background) and create  aa simple socket server that writes things down toa  file

Comment: no, because this is not resume-able. If I stop this process or restarted the daemon all these logs are lost.

Comment: well they wouldn't be lost, but you would have to calculate were you had stopped, what about using a delimiter string, or something that would induicate the last sent line before hte daemon had stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="file.json"
OUTPUT="filtered_file.json"
TEMPO="/tmp/tmpfile.json"
DELAY_SECONDS=60


LAST_MD5=(`md5sum "${INPUT}"`)

while :
do
    # Get filtered input
    cat "${INPUT}" | jq 'del(.timestamp)' > "${TEMPO}"

    # Count different lines between input and output
    DIFF_COUNT=`diff -n "${TEMPO}" "${OUTPUT}" |\
                cut -d" " -f2 | head -n 1`

    # If any change detected: update output file
    if [ "${DIFF_COUNT}" != "" ]
    then
        tail -n "${DIFF_COUNT}" ${TEMPO}
        tail -n "${DIFF_COUNT}" "${TEMPO}" >> "${OUTPUT}"
        LAST_MD5=(`md5sum "${INPUT}"`)
    fi

    # Check if input file has changed
    # it prevents using jq on every iterations
    MD5_INPUT=(`md5sum ${INPUT}`)
    while [ "${LAST_MD5}" = "${MD5_INPUT}" ]
    do
        sleep ${DELAY_SECONDS}
        MD5_INPUT=(`md5sum "${INPUT}"`)
    done
done
```

Comment: I wrote a very similar script, taking log rotation etc. into account and I used a couple of core and file utils. I will wriote something in C with a similar function soon, to supplement this functionality for easily scriptable workflows.